# Guess the presents someone will get by comparing wishlist attributes

Tags: algorithm, ruby, hash-map

```
#
# Guess the presents someone will get
# We compare a `wishlist` with many criteria to the `presents` and return an array with the names of the matching products. 
#
def guess_gifts(wishlist, presents)

  wishlist.map do |w|
    w[:name] if presents.include? w.reject { |key| key == :name }
  end.compact.uniq

end

guess_gifts([

{:name => "mini puzzle", :size => "small", :clatters => "yes", :weight => "light"},
{:name => "toy car", :size => "medium", :clatters => "a bit", :weight => "medium"},
{:name => "card game", :size => "small", :clatters => "no", :weight => "light"}

],
[

{:size => "medium", :clatters => "a bit", :weight => "medium"},
{:size => "small", :clatters => "yes", :weight => "light"}

])
```

In particular, I'd like to know whether `w.reject { |key| key == :name }` is the best way to remove the `:name` item.  Is there any shorter or faster way to do so?  I am often very surprised with Ruby capacity to shorten processes, so I'm wondering.

Comment: It's hard to review one line of code (possibly not even a complete line; I can't tell). Give us more context about what you are trying to achieve. Are you assigning the result of `h.reject { |key| key == :name }` to anything?

Comment: I'm using the result of the reject in a condition which compares this hash to an array with hashes in it like `if presents.include? w.reject { |key| key == :name }`

Comment: Could you just show more code then?

Comment: By the way, i don't know who put `-1` thinking it's a stupid question but when you start to train seriously on Ruby you really find smart shortcut you don't expect.

Comment: I just put the whole code in the question for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nice that you were able to implement `guess_gifts` as a single expression.

I don't recommend writing it that way, though.  For every item in the `wishlist`, you will scan the entire `presents` list for a match.  Wouldn't it be nice to just do a lookup instead?  You could do such a lookup if the `wishlist` were in a more convenient format.

```
def guess_gifts(wishlist, presents)
  # Transform the wishlist, mapping attributes to a list of names
  wishmap = Hash.new { |hash, attributes| hash[attributes] = [] }
  wishlist.each { |w| wishmap[w.reject { |k| k == :name }].push(w[:name]) }

  # Then just do the lookups
  presents.flat_map { |attributes| wishmap[attributes] }
end
```

Another benefit is that we're doing a map on `presents` rather than on `wishlist`, so I think we might not need to call `uniq` on the results.

Comment: definitely better logic ;)